# AS3 - P2P networking

Tags: actionscript-3, networking, p2p

I made a chat server in C/Linux, flash binary sockets and libev and it seems to be working pretty well, but I've been looking at flash peer-to-peer services and I'm wondering what could be done with this. It seems to be UDP, which may be a killer right there, but if it is possible to cut down on server costs by using P2P that would be amazing.

Is it possible to make a chat server entirely P2P and have no server costs? I noticed that it takes flash 10 which I don't think anything else in my application requires flash that recent, so that is obviously another down side. There are so many variables when looking at a new technology that it can be a bit overwhelming. I'd appreciate any criticisms of client/server vs P2P networking in Flash.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When I see something like Battle.net which I believe is largely P2P (Blizzard has to do some server work to match people up, but I think that's about it) it makes me think that if the game could support P2P (i.e. isn't an MMO) than this may be a good model for something like a chat server.

Comment: There must be some server cost , because You have to connect users  somehow , and only AIR can use UDP . You shold look at RTMFP protocol.

Comment: Adobe has a P2P solution called Cirrus at their labs http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/ which is used to handshake clients so they can exchange data directly without a server. Theoretically you wouldn't need a server when using Cirrus, however a client needs to know the keys returned by Cirrus for each client to be able connect to them. This is where a database comes into play which makes it easy to store keys and link display names to them. With a database comes a server..

Answer (score 0):

The costs of p2p are not null but minimized. Actually there needs to be a server that does the handshake and that brings forward the costs.

In order to use P2P and Actionscript you would need one of the following solutions:

- Use Cirrus - be ready for the cancellation of the service at one
  point and make sure you don't make any profit from it as Adobe
  mentions it's only for non-commercial usage.
- Use a hosting service that has p2p dedicated plans like influxis.com 
  or amazon -costs pretty much but can be scaled up and down meeting
  your needs and financial. Also it removes the hassle of installing
  and maintaining your own server.
- Acquire a four digit license($$$$) and host your own FMS 4.x Server -
  Adobe offers several versions that may fit your needs.
- Go open-source and use OpenRTMFP via Cumulus. Unfortunately the
  hand-shake between clients may not work each time(Adobe spent a great
  effort in making Stratus/Cirrus work behind firewalls). Another
  drawback is that Cumulus may only be associated with open-source
  projects.

For a start I believe that you are better with client-server rather that p2p as your project doesn't involve mandatory real-time interaction - as games do for example.

P2P cuts off some costs - especially for multimedia streaming - but it is still an expensive technology.

http://www.influxis.com/index.php/what/fms/enterprise/

http://aws.amazon.com/solutions/global-solution-providers/adobe/

https://github.com/OpenRTMFP/Cumulus